# The neighborhood of the most probable configuration

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Why do we study the properties of a function in the neighborhood of the most probable configuration instead of studying its properties for the most probable configuration?

[image]

where equation 2.20, it mentions is
$$ n_s = g_s e^{\alpha + \beta \epsilon_s} $$

The picture mentioned here is from the book "Introduction to Statistical Physics for Students" by A.J. Pointon.

Comment: you should be giving a link or reference  for your quote

Answer (score 10):

Because in the limit of a very large system it is vanishingly unlikely that it will actually be *in* the most probable configuration, but it is highly likely that it will be *near* the most probable configuration.

As an example, suppose I look at the $2N = 10^{24}$ gas molecules in the room I'm in, and I ask how many are in the left half of the room and how many are in the right half.  The probability that *exactly* $N = 5 \times 10^{23}$ molecules are in each half of the room is
$$
\frac{1}{2^{2N}} {2 N \choose N} \approx 8 \times 10^{-13},
$$
which is unlikely indeed!  But the probability that there are $N \pm \sqrt{N}/2$ molecules in each half of the room is about 68% (using the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.)

Comment: but wouldn't that violate the definition of the most probable configuration since it has the greatest probability? If the system is not likely to be in the most probable configuration then why do we call it the most probable configuration?

Comment: @Mr_Anonymous: Because all of the other configurations are even less likely than that.  When $N$ is large, the *absolute* probability of any one configuration is always going to be tiny;  but we can still talk meaningfully about which configuration has the greatest probability *relative* to the others.

Comment: Here's an analogy that might help:  the average height of an adult man in the US is 69.1 inches;  and if you looked at the distribution of heights, you'd find that it was the most probable height for an adult man.  But it is not particularly likely that any particular man is *exactly* this height.

Comment: (That said, Wolfram Alpha misled me about how likely the "exactly 50-50" configuration is;  it's a good deal more likely than I originally said, though still not terribly likely.  I've corrected my answer accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks for your satisfactory reply. (Highly Appreciated)